# SQLITE3 says "Table does not exist." Can't find the *ib files?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am making a text file management system in Python. I have created 2 tables using sqlite3 and at one point, have compared the values of their columns. Here, I get an error that table-2 does not exist (It is a select statement). I checked for answers on multiple questions and they said that I'd have to copy *ib files to my directory but I can't find them. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. All data and python files are stored in the same folder. 
 Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's the code for everyone (except Chuck Norris):

```
conn=Connection("User Data")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists U_Data (_UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Fname varchar2 (15) NOT NULL, Sname varchar2 (15) NOT NULL, Uname varchar2 (15) UNIQUE, Password varchar2(15) NOT NULL);")
conn.commit()

fileconn=Connection("File Data")
filecur=fileconn.cursor()
filecur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS F_Data (_FID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UID INTEGER(1000000), FileName varchar2 (15), Date_ varchar2 (15))")
fileconn.commit()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists U_Data (_UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Fname varchar2 (15) NOT NULL, Sname varchar2 (15) NOT NULL, Uname varchar2 (15) UNIQUE, Password varchar2(15) NOT NULL);")

filecur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS F_Data (_FID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UID INTEGER(1000000), FileName varchar2 (15), Date_ varchar2 (15))")

cur.execute("insert into U_Data (Fname, Sname, Uname, Password) values (?, ?, ?, ?);", (fname, lname, uname, password))

filecur.execute("insert into F_Data (UID, FileName, Date_) values (?, ?, ?)", ( uid, filename, today))

filecur.execute("SELECT * FROM F_Data, U_Data where F_Data.UID=_UID.U_Data")
```

Only the last statement doesn't work; the data is getting inserted and stuff. I think the problem is somehow with filecur.execute() in the last statement? U_Data's cursor is named cur. But then, how do I make it work for both of them? Can one cursor-name work for multiple cursors?

Comment: Without the code nobody can help you.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the `sqlite3.connect(...` and `.cursor()` statements. I assume you use **two** *Files* instead of **only** one File with two `tables`, therefore your `SELECT ...` couldn't find the `U_Data table` .

Comment: @stovfl I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand that. I did what you just said, anyway.

Comment: OH now I get it. I didn't know it had to be done that way. So I'll have to put both the tables within 1 connection?

Comment: @stovfl tried it and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: **One** File == **One** Conncection == `SELECT * FROM F_Data, U_Data` == **OK**

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @stovfl, two tables can be related only if they are in the same connection.